# Use MERGE on hyperedges with exact series of relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

**TLDR**: Is there a way to create a node (or to better say an hyperedge) only if it doesn't already exists but exactly with the specified series of relationships?

The long version is this one: suppose you have the following graph model, in which you describe different attacks. For each one of them you relate also the consequences of that particular attack (i.e. one "Attack" can have multiple "Consequence" node). Each consequence is also related to particular aspects such as security properties or impacts.

[image: single hyperedge]

So, to create this particular example I would do something like (suppose that the "Attack" node already exists):

```sql
MATCH (a:Attack {name:"Attack1"})
MERGE (i:Impact {name:"Execute unauthorized code"})
MERGE (p1:Property {name:"Confidentiality"})
MERGE (p2:Property {name:"Availability"})
MERGE (c:Consequence)-[:HAS_IMPACT]->(i)
MERGE (c)-[:AFFECTS]->(p1)
MERGE (c)-[:AFFECTS]->(p2)
MERGE (a)-[:HAS_CONSEQUENCE]->(c)
```

Now, suppose you want to add a second attack like this one:

[image: merging new node]

If I run the following Cypher code I don't get the expected result:

```sql
MATCH (a:Attack {name:"Attack2"})
MERGE (i:Impact {name:"Execute unauthorized code"})
MERGE (p:Property {name:"Confidentiality"})
MERGE (c:Consequence)-[:HAS_IMPACT]->(i)
MERGE (c)-[:AFFECTS]->(p)
MERGE (a)-[:HAS_CONSEQUENCE]->(c)
```

Basically due to the fact that the consequence of the "Attack2" is a subset of the "Attack1" I get this graph:

[image: real result of the merge]

To solve this problem I could use "CREATE" instead of "MERGE" when creating the "Consequence" node, but even this solution is not the perfect one, since it will create every time new nodes even if the right one already exists (with "right one" I mean the one that have the exact properties/impacts already related).

So, I was wondering if there's a specific approach to this kind of problem/situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new `Consequence` node, you can create it using `CREATE`  simply like this:

```
MATCH (a:Attack {name:"Attack2"})
CREATE (c:Consequence)
MERGE (i:Impact {name:"Execute unauthorized code"})
MERGE (p:Property {name:"Confidentiality"})
MERGE (c)-[:HAS_IMPACT]->(i)
MERGE (c)-[:AFFECTS]->(p)
MERGE (a)-[:HAS_CONSEQUENCE]->(c)
```

There are only two ways of doing this, either use `CREATE`, or provide some unique property in the `MERGE`, so that `MERGE` can differentiate the `Consequence` nodes on the basis of that. Like this:

```
MATCH (a:Attack {name:"Attack1"})
MERGE (i:Impact {name:"Execute unauthorized code"})
MERGE (p1:Property {name:"Confidentiality"})
MERGE (p2:Property {name:"Availability"})
MERGE (c:Consequence{id: 1})-[:HAS_IMPACT]->(i)
MERGE (c)-[:AFFECTS]->(p1)
MERGE (c)-[:AFFECTS]->(p2)
MERGE (a)-[:HAS_CONSEQUENCE]->(c)

MATCH (a:Attack {name:"Attack2"})
MERGE (i:Impact {name:"Execute unauthorized code"})
MERGE (p:Property {name:"Confidentiality"})
MERGE (c:Consequence{id: 2})-[:HAS_IMPACT]->(i)
MERGE (c)-[:AFFECTS]->(p)
MERGE (a)-[:HAS_CONSEQUENCE]->(c)
```

This will create two different `Consequence` nodes because the id will vary. But again for every different `id` a node will be created, even if all other properties are the same. Just pick the one suitable for your use-case.

Comment: I've tested it and your solution generates exactly the graph described in the 3rd image, meanwhile I was looking to get the graph like in the second image

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. Updated the answer

Comment: Yeah, but like I said I'm not really keen to use CREATE since it's not the ideal solution, since it will create a `consequence` node no matter what (i.e. if there's a right `consequence` node it will duplicate it)